# Read commandline argument by name

Tags: linux, bash

If I run a bash script as

```
./myscript.sh zone=A build=release
```

Is there someway I can read the arguments based on the parameters instead of using $1, $2?

Comment: You should take a look at _getopt_.

Comment: `set -k` causes post-command variable assignments to be treated the same as pre-command variable assignments, i.e. as modifications to the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Unix shells are an ancient technology, hash maps were known at the time but not "en vogue." They needed more than 1 byte to implement so the professionals didn't want to use such a wasteful technology.

What else can you do? The usual solution is [getopt(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt).

An alternative is to write all options to a file and source that:

```
echo "$@" | tr ' ' '\n' > options
. ./options

echo "zone=${zone}"
```

Comment: Note: Make sure each option goes into it's own line or the `source` / `.` will fail. `eval` might also work (needs no extra file).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are asking for:

```
A="try"
try="something"
echo ${!A}
> something
```

Answer (score 0):

This is close to what you want.

```
set -k
./myscript.sh zone=A build=release
```

will behave the same as

```
zone=A build=release ./myscript.sh
```

that is, `myscript.sh` will see `zone` and `build` with the given values in its environment.